# Integers bigger than 2000 with 36 divisors

Tags: elementary-number-theory

What are the first 2 integers bigger than 2000 with exactly 36 divisors each?
How do you go about solving a problem like this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

The method for working out the number of divisors of $n$ is to write $n$ as a product of powers of primes: $$n=p_1^{a_1}p_2^{a_2}\cdots p_r^{a_r}$$
where the $p_i$ are all different, and the $a_i$ are all at least $1$.

Then a factor of $n$ is a number of the form $p_1^{b_1}p_2^{b_2}\cdots p_r^{b_r}$, where for each $i$ we have $0\leq b_i\leq a_i$. There are thus $a_1+1$ choices for $b_1$, $a_2+1$ for $b_2$ and so on, so the number of factors of $n$ is $$(a_1+1)(a_2+1)\cdots(a_r+1).$$

Now you need to consider the possible ways to write $36$ as a product of factors (all of which are at least $2$, but having just one factor of $36$ is allowed). For each one you can convert to a sequence of $a_i$, for example $36=4\times 3\times 3$ gives $a_1=3,a_2=2,a_3=2$. Then you want to choose $p_i$ so that the resulting number is as small as possible, so you should put the $a_i$ in decreasing order and use the first few primes. So the smallest number of the form $p_1^3p_2^2p_3^2$ is $2^3\times 3^2\times 5^2=1800$. This is too small; the next one is $2^3\times 3^2\times 7^2=3528$. But there are a lot of other possibilities to check, since there are lots of ways to factorise $36$.

Answer (score 1):

Well, to find out the number of divisors, you factor the number and see. If $n=p_1^{\alpha_1}\cdot\dots p_k^{\alpha_k}$, then its number of divisors is $\tau(n)=(\alpha_1+1)\cdot\dots(\alpha_k+1)$.

Now we have to do this *backwards*: express 36 as a product (which can be done in a multitude of ways, like $36=2\cdot3\cdot6$ or $36=2\cdot2\cdot3\cdot3$), consider the factors as some $\alpha_i+1$, then take some random primes $p_i$ and combine them with the exponents $\alpha_i$ to get your $n$. Check all possible combinations, throw away everything that is smaller than 2000, and look for the two smallest numbers.

Admittedly, this is hardly faster than a [computer-assisted brute force search](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Select%5BRange%5B2000,%202500%5D,%20DivisorSigma%5B0,%20%23%5D%20%3D%3D%2036%20%26%5D).

Answer (score 1):

Some links for curious people :

[RonBrown : The minimal number with a given number of divisors](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0022314X05001009?via%3Dihub)

[primepuzzles.net : The least number N(d) with d number of divisors](http://www.primepuzzles.net/problems/prob_019.htm)

[oeis.org : A005179](https://oeis.org/A005179)

It is about the smallest number with a given divisor though, not a one bigger than a threshold, but it is interesting anyway.